# Floating Action Button in Android having icon not in center

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/button_floating_add"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="8dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The output looks like this:

[image: API-28]

I assume this is happening due to change in API version. I am using compileSDK and targetSDK version as `28` as well as the design and appcompat libraries as `28.0.0`. When I change API and design libraries version back to `26`, the output looks like:

[image: API 26]

Comment: Its Happening die to your image source i think so.. i.e drawable/button_floating_add.  I Suggest put all versions of png in folders like hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [floating action button anatomy](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#anatomy) states

> FAB containers come in two sizes:
>
> 1. Default (56 x 56dp)
> 2. Mini (40 x 40dp)

So in your case you want to use a small FAB. But you don't define it with `layout_width` and `layout_height`, because this only messes up the padding. You have to use the `app:fabSize` attribute and set it to [`SIZE_MINI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#SIZE_MINI):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    ... />
```

Comment: This seems to have solved the problem! But is this a change in API-28? I couldn't see it in the changelog of the design library

Comment: The implementation regarding the layouting might have changed. But this wouldn't be communicated anyhow. Regardless you might want to migrate to _AndroidX_ as the support library looses support more and more.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Android Asset Studio? They have almost every basic drawable to import in every size and density. heres link https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html

Answer (score 0):

use this property, as per view's height and width

```
app:fabCustomSize="40dp"
```

And suggest you.svg file instead of .png.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try these attributes,

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Answer (score 0):

The fab is a specialised type of view and you must adhere to its required needs. That being said its width and height should be `"wrap_content"`. In case you want your fab to be the mini version you can add `app:fabSize="mini"`.
You can use `layout_gravity` to set its screen position (in my example below that would be in the lower right corner). Also the icon must pe 24dp x 24dp. I recommend downloading your icons from https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline where you can choose the image size and all that.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
  android:id="@+id/fab"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
  android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
  android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onFabPressed()}"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24px"/>
```

The xml above is a working sample from one of my apps.
I hope this helps and have a great day!